# How can I use a derived type in a .net remoting call

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have a service which I connect to using .net remoting.

I want to call a method with an object which inherits from the type in the signature of the method.

But when I call with a derived type I get an IndexOutOfRangeException at the point of doing the remoting call:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{
    public string ExtraProperty { get; set; }
}

public class RemoteObject
{
    public void MyMethod(BaseClass obj)
    {
        /* things */
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static Main()
    {
        // pretend this is using System.Activator and 
        // System.Runtime.Remoting to do magic
        RemoteObject ro = RemotingHelper.GetRemoteObject();

        // works
        ro.MyMethod(new BaseClass());

        // IndexOutOfRangeException
        ro.MyMethod(new DerivedClass());        
    }
}
```

Presumably thats just how it is, but are there any work arounds?

Comment: Your DerivedClass needs to be known on the remote side. Also remoting while it won't go away, is now meant to be used internally only and no one will fix it.

Comment: Cf: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775694/system-runtime-remoting-messaging-imethodreturnmessage-outargs-property-throws-system-indexoutofrangeexception